# If $f$ is holomorphic in $D$ and $f(D)$ is not dense in $\mathbb{C}$, then $f$ has finite radial limits for almost all points on the unit circle.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D$ be the unit disc. If $f$ is holomorphic in $D$ and $f(D)$ is not dense in $\mathbb{C}$, then $f$ has finite radial limits for almost all points on the unit circle. Can anyone give me a hint? I have no idea to this question. Thanks very much!

Comment: Do you know this holds if $f(D)$ is bounded?

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Yes, it is true if $f(D)$ is bounded.

Comment: Then all you need is that Möbius transformations are automorphisms of the Riemann sphere.

Answer (score 3):

There is an open disk $D(c,r)$ disjoint from $f(D)$. Let $g(z)=\frac 1  {f(z)-c}$. Then $g$ is bounded holomorphic function on $D$ and this implies that $g$ has finite radial limits at almost all points on  the boundary (by theory of $H^{p}$ spaces). Hence $f$ has finite radial limits at almost all points on  the boundary.